# If condition inside of map() React

Tags: reactjs

I have a `map()`function that needs to display views based on a condition. I've looked at the React documentation on how to write conditions and this is how you can write a condition:

```
{if (loggedIn) ? (
  // Hello!
) : (
  // ByeBye!
)}
```

Here's the link: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

So, I tried to take that knowledge and implemant it in my React app. And it turned out like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="box">
        {this.props.collection.ids
          .filter(
            id =>
              // note: this is only passed when in top level of document
              this.props.collection.documents[id][
                this.props.schema.foreignKey
              ] === this.props.parentDocumentId
          )
          .map(id =>
            {if (this.props.schema.collectionName.length < 0 ? (

              <Expandable>
                <ObjectDisplay
                  key={id}
                  parentDocumentId={id}
                  schema={schema[this.props.schema.collectionName]}
                  value={this.props.collection.documents[id]}
                />
              </Expandable>

            ) : (
              <h1>hejsan</h1>
            )}
          )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But it doesn't work..! Here's the error:

[image: Screenshot]

I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: The error is a syntax one and is based on the fact that you are trying to use a [**ternary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) _and_ an [**if**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement incorrectly.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You are using both `ternary operator` and `if` condition, use any one.

**By ternary operator:**

```
.map(id => {
    return this.props.schema.collectionName.length < 0 ?
        <Expandable>
            <ObjectDisplay
                key={id}
                parentDocumentId={id}
                schema={schema[this.props.schema.collectionName]}
                value={this.props.collection.documents[id]}
            />
        </Expandable>
    :
        <h1>hejsan</h1>
}
```

**By if condition:**

```
.map(id => {
    if(this.props.schema.collectionName.length < 0)
        return <Expandable>
                  <ObjectDisplay
                      key={id}
                      parentDocumentId={id}
                      schema={schema[this.props.schema.collectionName]}
                      value={this.props.collection.documents[id]}
                  />
              </Expandable>
    return <h1>hejsan</h1>
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I did notice that I used both ://
Which one is preferred?

Comment: It is case by case but the fundamental difference is that if-else clause is a construct, ternary is an expression. And in JSX, only an expression can be placed **directly** under the JS block `{}`.

Comment: i think primarily opinion based, but what i prefer is: if you want to check only one condition then use ternary operator otherwise use if/else ladder for multiple conditions :)

Comment: Alright! But how does it now what's true and what's isn't? When using `if condition` I'm not using any `?` nor `:`.

Comment: @MartinNordström sorry didn't get the last one, can you explain more?

Answer (score 34):

If you're a minimalist like me. Say you only want to render a record with a list containing entries.

```
<div>
  {data.map((record) => (
    record.list.length > 0
      ? (<YourRenderComponent record={record} key={record.id} />)
      : null
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Answer (score 13):

There are two syntax errors in your ternary conditional:

1. remove the keyword `if`. Check the correct syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
2. You are missing a parenthesis in your code. If you format it like this:

   ```
   {(this.props.schema.collectionName.length < 0 ? 
      (<Expandable></Expandable>) 
      : (<h1>hejsan</h1>) 
   )}
   ```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 8):

This one I found simple solutions:

```
row = myArray.map((cell, i) => {

    if (i == myArray.length - 1) {
      return <div> Test Data 1</div>;
    }
    return <div> Test Data 2</div>;
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `if` keyword. It should just be `predicate ? true_result : false_result`.

Also `? :` is called ternary operator.

Comment: One can have `if` inside a function. Even if a ternary **also** works, you shouldn't suggest to remove something that's technically perfectly valid.

Comment: @Chris: that's a fair comment but the OP's error is based on a syntax error created by trying to combine both an `if` statement and the ternary operator incorrectly...

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing if statement with a ternary expression, that's why you're having a syntax error.
It might be easier for you to understand what's going on if you extract mapping function outside of your render method:

```
renderItem = (id) => {
    // just standard if statement
    if (this.props.schema.collectionName.length < 0) {
        return (
            <Expandable>
                <ObjectDisplay
                    key={id}
                    parentDocumentId={id}
                    schema={schema[this.props.schema.collectionName]}
                    value={this.props.collection.documents[id]}
                />
            </Expandable>
        );
    }
    return (
        <h1>hejsan</h1>
    );
}
```

Then just call it when mapping:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="box">
                { 
                    this.props.collection.ids
                        .filter(
                            id =>
                            // note: this is only passed when in top level of document
                            this.props.collection.documents[id][
                                this.props.schema.foreignKey
                            ] === this.props.parentDocumentId
                        )
                        .map(this.renderItem)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Of course, you could have used the ternary expression as well, it's a matter of preference. What you use, however, affects the readability, so make sure to check [different ways and tips to properly do conditional rendering in react and react native](https://kolosek.com/react-jsx-conditions).

Answer (score 2):

*Just in case:*

**`If` only**: (Use `&&` without `? :` or `else`)

When you don't have to return anything when `else`

**Examples:** (Array or Object)

```js
// const someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']
{someArray.map(
  (v) =>
    someCondition && (
      <></> // {v}
    )
)}

// const someObject = {a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'}
{Object.keys(someObject).map(
  (k) =>
    someCondition && (
      <></> // {someObject[k]} (Remember: add key={k} in wrapper)
    )
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

That the ternary operator works but not if-else statements is rather ridiculous and makes complex logic a pain. The former seems to be the only solution though.