# React Conditional Rendering - Loading Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-rendering

I am trying to call my Loading component when switching between the nav items. One each click it fetches new data so I'd like to place my Loading component there while we wait for the data to be loaded.

Where I'm confused is that I'm mapping over data to display my stories. In that map (below) do I add the ternary operator there to render the `Loading/> component? This is where I'm lost. I was trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969877/if-condition-inside-of-map-react).

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Story from "./Story";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Masthead from "./Masthead";
import LoadingBar from "./LoadingBar";

export default function News() {
  const { section } = useParams();
  console.log("Section: ", section);

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [results, setResults] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/${section}.json?api-key=4fzCTy6buRI5xtOkZzqo4FfEkzUVAJdr`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTimeout(() => setResults(data.results), 1500);
        console.log("Success ", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
        setError(error);
      });
  }, [section]);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!results) {
    return <LoadingBar type={"cylon"} color={"#193152"} />; // this Loading bar is called when first fetching data, but doesn't re-rending when refetching new data
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <Masthead />
        <ul className="stories">
          {results.map((story, index) => (        // Do I add the ternary operator here?
            <Story                             
              key={index}
              title={story.title}
              abstract={story.abstract}
              img={story.multimedia[0].url}
              alt={story.multimedia[0].caption}
              link={story.url}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

My App.js with Router

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Masthead from "./components/Masthead";
import News from "./components/News";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header title={"The React Times"} />
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Masthead} />
        <Route path="/news/:section" exact component={News} />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

and my Masthead section where I have my Nav items

```js
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

var sections = [
  "arts",
  "business",
  "health",
  "home",
  "movies",
  "opinion",
  "politics",
  "science",
  "sports",
  "technology",
];

export default function Masthead() {
  return (
    <div className="masthead">
      <ul>
        {sections.map((section) => {
          return (
            <li key={section}>
              <NavLink classname="navItem" to={`/news/${section}`}>
                {section}
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you're going to display the Loading Bar component whenever results is falsey. However, you don't set the results to null before you do the fetch, so it will still retain the contents from the last fetch, and the Loading Bar will never render again.

Comment: As a follow up suggestion to this explanation, it's somewhat jarring from a user experience perspective to remove all the stories while the next ones are still loading. Rather than setting the results to null, I'd advise adding an `isLoading` state which can display some status that the next stories are loading while still keeping the current ones on the screen.

Comment: when you say “some status” what do you mean visually? most sites use a loading spinner etc. i use loading bars in my Loading component

Comment: As @PatrickRoberts mentions, it's visually unattractive to see your list suddenly disappear to be replaced by a "loading" message and for new content to suddenly appear. What I usually do is to use a ```isLoading``` type of state which will trigger the visibility of an overlay that has the loading message appear. In the background, will be the "softened" image of the existing content. I then throw in some transition effects so that it doesn't feel too jarring.