# How can I write if statement inside a map in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write an if statement if invited is not undefined.

Here is my following code base:

```
{tabs[activeTab] === "Pending" &&
    userInvitedList.map((user, index) => (
    {user.invited.pending && ()}
    <InviteSentList
      user={user}
      index={index}
      selected={selected}
      handleSelect={handleSelect}
    />
  ))}
```

How can I check `user.invited.pending` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
{tabs[activeTab] === "Pending" &&
    userInvitedList.map((user, index) => (
    {user.invited.pending && 
             <InviteSentList
                key={index} 
                user={user}
                index={index}
                selected={selected}
               handleSelect={handleSelect}
              />
      }
  ))}
```

You can refer more in details here [if condition inside map][1]

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969877/if-condition-inside-of-map-react#:~:text=I%20have%20a%20map(),](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969877/if-condition-inside-of-map-react#:%7E:text=I%20have%20a%20map(),))%20%3A%20(%20%2F%2F%20ByeBye!%20)%7D

Answer (score 0):

If you want show `InviteSentList` when `user.invited.pending` is not `undefined`, you just update like this:

```
{user.invited.pending && (
    <InviteSentList
      user={user}
      index={index}
      selected={selected}
      handleSelect={handleSelect}
      key={user.id} // unique
    />
)}
```

Note: You need to add `key` props

Answer (score 0):

if you put if statement or something like this in map, you can remove () after arrow function and change with curly brackets {}. You can do this:

```
{tabs[activeTab] === "Pending" &&
 userInvitedList.map((user, index) => {
  user.invited.pending && (
    <InviteSentList
     key={index}
     user={user}
     index={index}
     selected={selected}
     handleSelect={handleSelect}
   />
  )}
)}
```

Comment: you need to add `return` if you use curly bracket

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
{tabs[activeTab] === "Pending" &&
          userInvitedList.map((user, index) => {
            return user.invited.pending ? (
              <InviteSentList
                user={user}
                index={index}
                selected={selected}
                handleSelect={handleSelect}
              />
            ) : null;
          })}
```